# How to act on different random responses (in my text adventure game)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am making a text adventure game in python, and I have randomised a response to my each of my first choices(A,B,C), now lets say he does not find anything when choosing A. How would I basically say;

"if nothing found, (* **insert another list of choices here** *)"

into my code? I cant quite seem to find an answer, so I'm hoping someone here knows it, thanks!
Here's my code so far:

```
import time
import random

print ('You suddenly jolt up from the sleeping bag, awoken by the howling of nearby wolves.\nYou are cold, shivering and starving, and the few things that are still visible,\nare lit up only by the moon, and notice you are in the middle of a forest.\n')
ch1 = str(input(' Do you: \nA: Use your hands to search around\nB: Sleep again until morning\nC: Get up, and attempt to run away from the wolves in the dark:\n'))

responsesA = [
    'You found a torch!',
    'You did not find anything.'
    ]

responsesB = [
    'You fell asleep again cold and hungry.',
    'You are unable to sleep.'
    ]

responsesC = [
    'You start running as fast as you can and successfuly escape!',
    'You trip and injure knee.'
    ]


if ch1 in ['A']:
    print (random.choice(responsesA))

if ch1 in ['B']:
    print (random.choice(responsesB))

if ch1 in ['C']:
    print (random.choice(responsesC))
```

Is there anything I should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
if ch1 in ['A']:
    random_value = random.choice(responsesA)
    print(random_value)
    if random_value == 'You did not find anything.':
       # insert another list of choices here
```

Instead of printing out the random value, keep it in a variable and then check if the random value was "no value" and handle it accordingly.

Comment: wow thank you for your fast reply, i will try it out. I tried out a similar  way to do it, but i put '=' instead of '==", whoops!